# Showing Date only from SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I am sending **Date** from **WPF** to **ModelClass** by this method.......

```
private void buttonNTSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ModelClass model = new ModelClass();
    model.TaskInsertion(textBoxNTSubject.Text, textBoxNTType.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(datePickerNT.SelectedDate), textBoxNTTitle.Text, textBoxNTDetail.Text);
}
```

The **Date** is being inserted in database by this method...

```
public void TaskInsertion(string subject, string type, DateTime dueDate, string title, string detail)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Tbl_Task (Email, Subject, Type, DueDate, Title, Detail) VALUES ('" + userEmail + "', '" + subject + "' , '" + type + "', '" + dueDate.Date + "', '" + title + "', '" + detail + "')";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

But Whenever I try to retrieve only **Date** from Database to a **DataGrid**, still the **Time** with **Date** is showing..

```
public DataTable OverDueCurrentTask()
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {

        DateTime DateToday = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
        string query = "DECLARE @sDate Date SET @sDate = '" + DateToday.Date + "' SELECT Title, Subject, Type, DueDate FROM Tbl_Task WHERE DueDate >= @sDate";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dataTbl = new DataTable("Tbl_Task");
        dataAdp.Fill(dataTbl);
        dataAdp.Update(dataTbl);
        return dataTbl;

    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

        conn.Close();
        return null;

    }
}
```

How to show **Date** without showing the **Time**?
N.B. In Database, DueDate is a Date Type column.

Comment: Although Insert query is working but I would recommend to use SqlCommand Parameters. Beware of SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Totally agree with @Hassan for sql injection. About the value returned to the client, it's a problem of formatting. So, I think is better to delegate this task to the application layer (the nearest to the front end). In this case you can show the `.ToShortDateString()` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast `DueDate` column `cast([DueDate] as date) > = @sDate`. While `sDate` is already declared as `date`.

```
string query = @"DECLARE @sDate Date SET @sDate = '" + DateToday.Date + "' 
               SELECT Title, Subject, Type, cast([DueDate] as date) as DueDate FROM Tbl_Task 
               WHERE cast([DueDate] as date) >= @sDate";
```

Although it completes answer but you need to make subtle changes in the code, to avoid SQL injection attacks. Use [SqlCommand Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx). Add `using` blocks in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can do this in C# as well.  In the SQL query, you can use:

```
select cast([date] as date) as dateonly
```

To convert the `datetime` to a `date`.

The following Edit was provided by Dan Guzman:

The C# code to build the query string needed for the application is:

```
string query = "DECLARE @sDate Date SET @sDate = '" + DateToday.Date + "' SELECT Title, Subject, Type, CAST(DueDate AS date) AS DueDate FROM Tbl_Task WHERE DueDate >= @sDate;";
```

Comment: Can you please precisely provide the full query to retrieve the date only from database? I am not expert in SQL.